# What is the right way to design Python / SQLite application without repeating connection part?

Tags: python, sqlite

im trying to develop a simple application where multiple business objects are saved to the sqlite database. I have several business objects for which I want to program save/update/delete methods. For each of the classes and methods within those classes I always create a new connection. For example:

```
import sqlite3
db = "mydb.db"

class BusinessObject1:
    ...
    def save_to_db(self, db):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        with conn:
            cur.execute("...")

    def delete_from_db(self, db):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        with conn:
            cur.execute("...")

class BusinessObject2:
    ...
    def save_to_db(self, db):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        with conn:
            cur.execute("...")

    def delete_from_db(self, db):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        with conn:
            cur.execute("...")
```

It doesn't feel like a good design solution (not DRY). Can someone propose a better design for this? I have around 20 Business objects and 4-8 methods for each and a record table where all these objects are included. Typing conn=sqlite3.connect(db) every time simply cannot be the right way. And if I'll decide to change to MySQL or PostgreSQL I would need to refactor the whole project.

Thanks!

Comment: why would you connect to the database in every single method? That's what a constructor is for: do something like `self.conn = sqlite3.connect(…)` in `__init__`, instead of having to supply the `db` object to every method that interacts with the database.

Comment: The business object shouldn't be responsible for the implementation of connecting to a database.

Comment: @PeterWood hm, you propose that in MVC sense the business object is not the model, but the controller?

Comment: I don't know about MVC or its bearing on this issue. The [CRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-responsibility-collaboration_card) (Class, Responsibility, Collaboration) analysis could say your class is responsible for creating custom SQL statements and needs to collaborate with an object which can process those SQL statements. But I don't know. There are many ways to slice it.

Answer (score 0):

Then you might want to separate the connection handler from the class object or you can do as the comment above suggesting to put the connection inside the class constructor.

If for some reason you can't do both you can still add a `staticmethod` to your class that will handle the connection. It's not ideal but it's still better than your solution:

```
@staticmethod
def create_connection(db_file):

    conn = None

    try:
        with sqlite3.connect(db_file) as conn:
            return conn
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("Can't connect to database, error:", e, sep="\n")

    return conn
```

Then you add a parameter to your other methods which will be the returned `create_connection` method:

```
def save_to_db(self, connection):
        cur = connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("...")
```

This way you can separate your connect object from your class object:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    conn = BusinessObject1.create_connection(db)

    b1 = BusinessObject1(...)
    b1.save_to_db(conn)
```